# How to hide tr tag in a table if the td has NIL value using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently having problem hiding tr tag if the td tag has NIL value using javascript, below is the code for table and it occurs as the 3rd table as i am currently developing an chrome extension and that matters so as to target it.

Here is what i tried in jquery but i need to do this in javascript:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    if (tr.find('td:eq(0)').text()=="NIL"
        && tr.find('td:eq(1)').text()=="NIL"
        && tr.find('td:eq(2)').text()=="NIL"
    ) tr.addClass('hidden');
});
```

Here is the table code:

```
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="22%" height="30" rowspan=5 valign=top>
                <font color=#FFFFFF>Assignments</font>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                NIL
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                NIL
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                NIL
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                NIL
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                NIL
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: You can use jQuery in Chrome extensions, for what it's worth. Failing that, the table element has a javascript property (an array) `rows` and each of them have a property `cells`(also an array). You could access the contents of the top-left cell with `tableElem.rows[0].cells[0].innerText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want:

```js
$("table td:contains('NIL')").closest("tr").css("color", "red");

/* ABOVE HERE IS JUST FOR DEMO CHANGING OF COLOR
   BUT USE FOLLOWING TO HIDE 
$("table td:contains('NIL')").closest("tr").hide();
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="22%" height="30" rowspan=6 valign=top>
      <font>Assignments</font>
    </td>
    <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
      NIL
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
      NIL
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
      NIL
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
      NIL
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
      NIL
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
      Not a " N I L"
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update:**

```js
$("table table table td:contains('NIL')").closest("tr").css("color", "red");

/* ABOVE HERE IS JUST FOR DEMO CHANGING OF COLOR
   BUT USE FOLLOWING TO HIDE 
$("table td:contains('NIL')").closest("tr").hide();
*/
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor=#5A768D width="22%" height="30" rowspan=6 valign=top>
                  <font>Assignments</font>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                  NIL
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                  NIL
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                  NIL
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                  NIL
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                  NIL
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor='#EDEADE' width="76%" height="30">
                  Not a " N I L"
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>Second Table</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>First Table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i have the table code inside a table like /table/table/table how can i select that?

Comment: @rahulkapoor check the **Updated Snippet**.